# storing data to database using python and retrieving it in a node.js app

Tags: python, node.js, database

The following code annotates a video with labels (or "tags") that are selected based on the image content.

```
import argparse

from google.cloud import videointelligence


def analyze_labels(path):
    """ Detects labels given a GCS path. """
    video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
    features = [videointelligence.enums.Feature.LABEL_DETECTION]
    operation = video_client.annotate_video(path, features=features)
    print('\nProcessing video for label annotations:')

    result = operation.result(timeout=90)
    print('\nFinished processing.')

    segment_labels = result.annotation_results[0].segment_label_annotations
    for i, segment_label in enumerate(segment_labels):
        print('Video label description: {}'.format(
            segment_label.entity.description))
        for category_entity in segment_label.category_entities:
            print('\tLabel category description: {}'.format(
                category_entity.description))

        for i, segment in enumerate(segment_label.segments):
            start_time = (segment.segment.start_time_offset.seconds +
                          segment.segment.start_time_offset.nanos / 1e9)
            end_time = (segment.segment.end_time_offset.seconds +
                        segment.segment.end_time_offset.nanos / 1e9)
            positions = '{}s to {}s'.format(start_time, end_time)
            confidence = segment.confidence
            print('\tSegment {}: {}'.format(i, positions))
            print('\tConfidence: {}'.format(confidence))
        print('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('path', help='GCS file path for label detection.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    analyze_labels(args.path)
```

The code prints the result to the terminal.

I want to store the `Video label description`, `Label category description` and `confidence` values to a Database(maybe MongoDB) and later retrieve it in a Noje.js application.

How can I do that or Is there any other better way?

Comment: Who's stopping you? You can simply use sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from doing that; as long as both your python program and your Node.js program agree on how data is being stored, you should have no trouble storing and retrieving simple strings. MongoDB, being a key/value store, would work well if you will know the keys you need to retrieve beforehand; something like SQLite might be better if you want to retrieve data based on some criteria without knowing an exact key. Both Node.js and Python have MongoDB/SQLite clients that function perfectly well.